# What is the value of the following limit?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

What is the value of $$\limsup_{x\to \pi} \sin(x)$$ ?

Comment: Sine is continuous so this is the same as the limit, so again as sine is continuous, this is the same as the value of sine at $\pi$ which is $0$.

Comment: If [the solution provided by user45150](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/296451/what-is-the-value-of-the-following-limit#comment644617_296451) doesn't help you understand the problem, perhaps it would be best if you could describe what's confusing you.

Comment: @user45150  Isn't it equal to 1? Why isn't $\pi/2$ in the neighborhood of $\pi$?

Comment: Which neighborhood of $\pi$?  It has many, and $\pi/2$ is not in all of them.

Answer (score 1):

(Getting this question off the unanswered list...)

As user45150 wrote, the sine function is continuous, so
$$\limsup_{x\to\pi} \sin(x) = \lim_{x\to\pi} \sin(x)= \sin(\pi) = 0.$$